# Missing ASP.NET tab in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, deployment, configuration

Hmm. I'm trying to deploy a web service to a new server and there is no ASP.NET tab. I've tried running  `aspnet_regiis` from ASP.NET 2.0 directory but this doesn't seem to work. Any ideas anyone?

Answer (score 13):

If you've had (or have...) VMware Server installed on this particular machine, the following steps will most likely fix the issue with minimal pain:

1. Stop the IISAdmin service (and its dependencies)
2. Open `%windir%\system32\inetsrv\MetaBase.xml` in a text editor
3. Delete the line that reads `Enable32BitAppOnWin64="TRUE"`
4. Restart your services using `iisreset /start`

Comment: This works as long as you don't need to run a 32bit application :(

Answer (score 6):

Did you try uninstalling and then reinstalling ASP.NET?

i.e.

```
aspnet_regiis -u
```

and then

```
aspnet_regiis -i
```

The uninstall and then reinstall worked for me before.

Answer (score 5):

The default install for IIS doesn't include ASP or .Net. You need to enable those in Windows Features menu where you installed IIS from. [This](http://www.visualwin.com/ASP.NET/) shows the basic steps - they may be different for your IIS version and host OS.

Answer (score 4):

This can have multiple causes ranging from installing IIS after the .NET Framework or the IIS metabase getting corrupted. The order I would go with is:

1. **reinstall ASP.NET** (as noted above: `aspnet_regiis -u` and then `aspnet_regiis -i` (found in the *Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\vX.Y.Z* directory)
2. **If #1 does not resolve it, then reinstall IIS** (remove/reinstall using Add/Remove Windows Components from Add/Remove Programs on XP/2003 or from Programs Control Panel Applet on Vista)

Answer (score 1):

Is this IIS6? I think you can go to the

1. Add/Remove Software
2. Windows Components
3. IIS
4. Make sure that ASP.NET is checked. I think this installs
   support for ASP.Net
5. re-run aspnet_regiis

Comment: ASP.net is checked unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

I found proper way. Consolidating and summerizing the method for windows 7.

1. Click Start, and then click Control Panel.
2. In Control Panel, click Programs, and then click Turn Windows features on or off.
3. VERY IMPORTANT! In the Windows Features dialog box, click Internet Information Services to install the default features, and then select the following additional features:

ASP.NET,.NET Extensibility , Request Filtering , ISAPI,ISAPI Extensions
Click OK to close the Windows Features dialog box.

4.To verify that IIS installed successfully, type the following into a Web browser:

```
http://localhost
```

You should see the default IIS Welcome page

5.Uninstall ASP.NET with IIS aspnet_regiis -u

6.Reinstall aspnet_regiis -i.

7.ReInstall .NET framework 4 in order IIS to recognize v4 in application pool.

Refer:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h.aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731252%28v=WS.10%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I resolved my problem with the following steps:

> 1) Set the necessary permissions in "C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv" and subfolders.
>
> 2) Do not compact this folder, subfolders or files inside.

Answer (score 0):

reinstall IIS

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you're setting up a new server, I assume it's a Windows Server 2008 (IIS7) or 2008 R2 (IIS7.5). In either case, ASP.NET support is not configured by default (as others have mentioned). Check out the following documentation: [Deploying an ASP.NEt Server (IIS7)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731252%28v=WS.10%29.aspx)